# Error Type: Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01A8) Object required in asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I m new asp..

And tried to access with [code](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:519f)

But it shows error like this.,

> Error Type:
> Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01A8)
> Object required: ''
> on line 163

The error showed because of this lines,

```
<%
do while not getgroups2.eof 
    pkOrgGroups2=getgroups2("pkOrgGroups")
    ogGroup2=getgroups2("ogGroup")
    ogLogo2 =getgroups2("ogLogo")
%>
```

May i know for which reason of my code it shows like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty sure that's *classic* ASP, not ASP.NET.  They are two different things....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two sure ways to get an "Object required" error:

Trying to use `Set` when assigning a non-object:

```
>> Set x = "non-object/string"
>>
Error Number:       424
Error Description:  Object required
```

Trying to call a method on a non-object:

```
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(x)
>> If x.eof Then x = "whatever"
>>
Empty
Error Number:       424
Error Description:  Object required
```

or:

```
>> x = "nix"
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(x)
>> If x.eof Then x = "whatever"
>>
String
Error Number:       424
Error Description:  Object required
```

As there is no `Set` in the code you posted, one has to assume that `getgroups2` is not an object. Use TypeName() to check.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner: i need to use some condition.. can you please help?